# Eclipse closing unexpectedly when auto suggestion comes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for Android development. The problem is that it's getting closed unexpectedly when auto suggesting dropdown comes while writing code.

**eclipse.ini file:**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also had the same problem,
>
> You can add ***-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla*** to the end of your **eclipse.ini** file. Note that this not will work when using the OpenJDK.